# Magento 2 : Add template below addtocart button and replace quantity and addtocart template from product detail page

Tags: magento2, addtocart, magento-2.0.7

I have two requirements

1. Add template below addtocart button.
2. Replace the core template of quantity and addtocart button with my own template. How to achieve this

My layout file is below:-

**catalog_product_view.xml**

```
<referenceContainer name="product.info.main">
    <block class="Vendor\Modulename\Block\Product\View\Stock"
        name="product.view.stock"
        template="Vendor_Modulename::product/view/stock.phtml"
        after="product.info.addtocart" ifconfig="form_stock/form_group_general/status">
    </block>
</referenceContainer>
```

By using this template. I am getting my template on the product detail page below the product name. but my requirement has different which is what I have shown above. If anybody knows then please guide me.

Answer (score 1):

To add template on product page exactly below the `Add to Cart` button:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.options.wrapper.bottom">
            <block
                class="[ProjectName]\[ModuleName]\Block\Catalog\Product\[BlockName]"
                name="product.info.[block_name]"
                template="[ProjectName]_[ModuleName]::catalog/product/[block_name].phtml"
                after="product.info.addtocart"/>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

To replace `Quantity` input and `Add to Cart` button template (both are on same file):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.options.wrapper.bottom">
            <block
                name="product.info.addtocart"
                template="[ProjectName]_[ModuleName]::catalog/product/[block_name].phtml"/>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

The default template is located in `vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/tempates/product/view/addtocart.phtml`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way to add a template on product page using your module's `catalog_product_view.xml` file

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart">
    <block class="Vendorname\Module\Block\Product\View\Extra"
                    name="product.view.extra"
                    template="Vendorname_Module::product/view/extra.phtml"
                    after="-"></block>
</referenceBlock>
<!-- for config products -->
<referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart.additional">
    <block class="Vendorname\Module\Block\Product\View\Extra"
                    name="product.view.extra"
                    template="Vendorname_Module::product/view/extra.phtml"
                    after="-"></block>
</referenceBlock>
```

And you can overwrite addtocart.phtml using this

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart">
    <action method="setTemplate">
        <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendorname_Module::catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml</argument>
    </action>
</referenceBlock>
<referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart.additional">
    <action method="setTemplate">
        <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendorname_Module::catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml</argument>
    </action>
</referenceBlock>
```